# What are the latest version on Silverlight 2.0 tools for VS2008 SP1

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I want to develop a silverlight 2.0 application.

What are the latest versions I need to install
to do this for VS2008 SP1 please??

Malcolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Silverlight 2 Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=c22d6a7b-546f-4407-8ef6-d60c8ee221ed&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

On top of SilverLight 2 Tools.  You may consider Microsoft Expression Blend.  Make sure you also update Blend to SP1.  Blend is very useful for editing XAML files.  VS 2008 doesn't provide a good UI to do that.

Comment: I'd second that. In my opinion Blend is mandatory for any Silverlight or WPF UI work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really interested in everything you need to get started with silverlight view the guide on thier website.  This has the link to the proper silverlight tools for visual studio

http://silverlight.net/getstarted

Also the latest realease of Silverlight 3.0 (which cannot be installed concurrently with 2.0)

http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx